# When I reload my site it sends me to a different part then I was prior to the reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When I am on my site and reload it will scroll the page to a different part.

Lets say I am looking at the table of contents, then I reload the page I will get scrolled to somewhere else like the conclusion.

But when I reload the page at the conclusion it will bounce back to the table of contents and be stuck in a loop like that.

This is incredibly annoying because when I'm trying to do dev work and reload the page to see my changes I have to scroll all the way up.

I have literally no idea what could be causing this, there's no href its attached to.

Another thing is that the only part it doesn't do this is at the very bottom. It also seems random where it sends me and how far the page scrolls. As far as I can tell there is no pattern.

Also this is on chrome.

Comment: Can you please fill your post with code? Without code, no error analysis can take place.

Comment: @Lukas What code I don't know where the problem could be and I can't exactly share all the code with you.

Comment: Sounds something to do with JS, or elements not showing up immediately when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Lee Yeh I think thats whats happening, I have some javascript that changes the formatting, this makes the website longer so that moves the position of the page that I'm on. However I'm not sure how I would fix that.